# Second wp_query doesn't appear to be working

Tags: wp-query

I've set up this query in Wordpress to find all associated news for a company:

```
    <h2 class="heading">Related News</h2>   
    <?php $link = get_the_title(); ?>
    <?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>  
    <?php $post_link = get_post_permalink(); ?>
    <?php $post_title = get_the_title(); ?>                        
    <?php  if (get_field('featured_companies') != "") { ?>
        <p style="margin:0px!IMPORTANT;">
        <?php foreach(get_field('featured_companies') as $post): ?>
            <?php $company = get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php if ($company == $link) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $post_link; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a><br />
            <?php } ?> 
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I then wanted to create the same thing but find all events associated with the company. Even though news and events are setup exactly the same way it doesn't seem to work, what am I missing???

```
    <h2 class="heading">Related Events</h2>
    <?php $link_e = get_the_title(); ?> 
    <?php $portfolioloop_e = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $portfolioloop_e->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop_e->the_post(); ?>  
    <?php $post_link_e = get_post_permalink(); ?>
    <?php $post_title_e = get_the_title(); ?>                        
    <?php  if (get_field('featured_companies') != "") { ?>
        <p style="margin:0px!IMPORTANT;">
        <?php foreach(get_field('featured_companies') as $post_e): ?>
            <?php $company_e = get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php if ($company_e == $link_e) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $post_link_e; ?>"><?php echo $post_title_e; ?></a><br />
            <?php } ?> 
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </p>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I tried wp_reset_query, but I don't have any real clue what to do!

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r()` `$portfolioloop` and `$portfolioloop_e`? Are you actually managing to get posts on both queries?

Comment: @m0r7if3r The first block of code works great. The second doesn't - I've tried echoing stuff throughout the loops which works until I put it within the $company_e == $link_e as the titles are different, not sure how they're different though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `$post_e` to this line and it worked:

```
<?php $company_e = get_the_title($post_e); ?>
```

Thanks for both your help, it triggered some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling get_post_permalink etc, I think you may need to add wp_reset_postdata(); as well, per this section in the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query

Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, thought it may be something like but it didn't seem to work. I put it after both the wp_reset_query's.